# How to use time-stamp in spring-data-neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

We are using mysql along with hibernate4 for one of our application. We are storing some error messages in the DB.
Below is the class property which used to stores the current time in DB.

```
@Column(name = "generation_ts")
private java.sql.Timestamp generationTs;
```

Now we are trying to store this data in the Neo4J graph DB along with the mysql DB. Also we don't want to change the current behavior of the class.

When I am trying to save this object in Neo4J DB it is throwing the Exception as below:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
>       at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:202)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToObjectConverter.convert(ObjectToObjectConverter.java:71)

I have tried [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#example). But It also gives the same exception.

So is there any other way by which I can save this object to mysql DB as well as to Neo4j DB.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this to trigger the right converter:

```
@GraphProperty(propertyType=long.class)
private java.sql.Timestamp generationTs;
```

Comment: Yes I have read about this. In the same document. But it is not converting the Timestamp into Long value. It has also mentioned that after annotating the filed **"there has to be a Converter registered in the Spring-Config"**. So can you please help me how to write this converter?

Comment: There is an out-of the box converter for Date to Long, and as Timestamp is a subclass of Date it should work directly.

Comment: Yes because Neo4j has no data-type (yet) so Long or String is what is commonly used.

Comment: I have used the same way you have mentioned in above comment. But its doing nothing. I am not getting any property with name generationTs in the node created. Also when I have changes the "propertyType" to String it's giving the same exception as mentioned in the question.